# How to get type of function name (type fnName = FunctionName<typeof fn>)?

Tags: typescript

I need something like `getFunctionName`:

```
type FunctionName<F extends (...args: any[]) => any> = getFunctionName F;
```

Use case:

```
function foo() {
}

type FooName = FunctionName<typeof foo>; // should be resolved to "foo"
```

Is anything like this possible?

Comment: Don't think so, since `foo` can either be a function declaration or a variable of a function type, and there is no way to distinguish between the two in the type system, `foo` might not even have a name...

Comment: Maybe this might be an ok work around: `function foo() {} let fooVar = { foo }; type FooName = keyof typeof fooVar;` The field in `fooVar` is implicitly typed the same as the function although that is not guarantee that will be the declared name